# An elementary question about the definition of convergence of a sequence in metric spaces: should we include $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ or not?

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, definition

Let $(X,d_{X})$ be a metric space and $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence which lies in $X$.

Some people define its convergence to some point $x\in X$ as follows:

\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists N\in\mathbb{N})(n\geq N\Rightarrow d_{X}(x_{n},x) < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

I would like to know if they omit the condition $n\in\mathbb{N}$ or if it unnecessary indeed.

Precisely speaking, I would like to know if the following definition is adequate:
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists N\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(n\geq N\Rightarrow d_{X}(x_{n},x) < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\forall n$ and $n\geq N$ does not make sense in the last sentence, because if there exists some $N$ such that only for $n\geq N$ the sentence is true, then is not for all $n$ that the sentence is true. Your first question: it is implicit that $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes, your version is the more technically precise way of writing what is meant.

Comment: @Ted But that's the point: for small enough $\epsilon$ it will *not* be the case that the predicate is true for all $n$, but it is true if $n \geq N$ for some $N$.

Comment: Since $x_n$ wasn't defined when $n$ isn't a natural...